# Is there any way to rename 'set'

Tags: tcl

While trying to rename the `set` function, 
I got the error `too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)` (see below).

Perhaps because `rename` uses `set` internally. Is there any way to override this behaviour?

```
rename set Set
too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)
    while executing
"set cmd [lindex $args 0]"
    (procedure "::unknown" line 8)
    invoked from within
"set cmd [lindex $args 0]"
    (procedure "::unknown" line 8)
    invoked from within
"set cmd [lindex $args 0]"
    procedure "::unknown" line 8
    ...
```

Comment: Looks like you'll have to redefine [proc `unknown`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/unknown.htm)  before you rename `set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rename` command is a built-in command of Tcl, and does not depend on any other commands. However, the interactive evaluation loop does use `set` quite a bit in its history management code, as does the `unknown` command which handles what to do when a command name is not resolved to an existing command. That triggers an infinite loop as handling what to do when `set` is absent requires `set` to be present as part of the handling code; the stack protection code (see `interp recursionlimit`) eventually kills things off…

The simplest fix is to make sure that you keep *something* in place called `set`.

```
# Make our replacement
proc replacement_set {varName {value ""}} {
    # This is 8.6-specific code, but you can do other equivalent things
    tailcall old_set {*}[lrange [info level 0] 1 end]
}

# Swap things in, with both renames on the same line...
rename set old_set; rename replacement_set set
```

Note that you don't need to be quite as careful in a script.

Comment: Thanks Donal but there is a slight issue that I have no clue about.
I am using the 8.4 with following code
 `proc replacement_set {varName {value ""}} {
     
# This is 8.6-specific code, but you can do other equivalent things

  ;puts "In New Set";
     ;uplevel 1 "old_set [lrange [info level 0] 1 end]";
 }`

Comment: It executes as below and executes the puts inside multiple times - any clue on this
() 2 % rename set old_set; rename replacement_set set
In New Set
In New Set
In New Set
() 3 % set x y
In New Set
In New Set
In New Set
In New Set
In New Set
In New Set
In New Set
y
In New Set
In New Set
In New Set

Comment: it does work nicely though - it just executes the original set multiple number of times - which works but will be good to avoid